# How to hide Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database I am renaming a table. I tried to rename it by using

```
exec sp_rename Student,Students
```

but I got the message:

> Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures.

How can I avoid getting this message?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider telling us what you have tried? We can help with editing code but won't write code for you.

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about? It also sounds as if that is actually a message from your SQL client, rather then from the DBMS itself. So which SQL client are you using?

Comment: Sql Server am using

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, this message cannot be suppressed.*

There was a [Microsoft Connect ticket](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/266048/sp-rename-suppress-caution-warning-message) submitted by our very own [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand), but it was closed as won't fix.

Keep in mind that this message isn't an error - it's not even a warning - it's just a cautionary message saying, "Be careful."

---

<sup>*Okay, it *can* be suppressed, but it involves modifying the source code of `sp_rename`, which is **[not recommended](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bb121a87-2681-4a9f-b38a-6870657c95e4/sprename-suppress-warning-message?forum=transactsql)**.</sup>

Comment: Funny that I much prefer microsoft's "won't fix" responses over "we provided an option in the registry at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Microsoft\Entity....."

Comment: So, its a warning.

Comment: It can be suppressed, albeit in a weird way. Just make a copy of sp_rename in your database, name it something else, and remove the line: raiserror(15477,-1,-1) from it. Now you can use your own rename stored proc, it works exactly the same as the MS one, but just doesn't give that error message.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is this:

Extract the source code of sp_rename from your Master database.
Make a copy of it somewhere else under a different name e.g. "quiet_rename"
Remove / comment out this line from the code:

```
raiserror(15477,-1,-1)
```

now you have your own local copy of sp_rename without the annoying error message included.

Answer (score -1):

> Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures.

You can verify that the changes have been made by issuing a SELECT against the table using new table name. SQL Server is also nice enough to warn us that renaming an object can break scripts and stored procedures. What this means is if you have used table/column names in any script/stored procedure it will not be updated automatically, you will need to go through your scripts/stored procedures manually and update them accordingly.

Hope This Helps!